# Server.Create Object Failed error   

Tags: asp-classic, regsvr32, createobject

I am debugging some old ASP code and have stumbled upon the following error:

Server.CreateObject Failed

Here's the line of code where I got the error:

```
Set Session("SessionBoolian") = Server.CreateObject("DBUtils.SQLExpression")
```

Where is  DBUtils.SQLExpression located? I can't seem to find a reference to it in the code. How is it set?

I do have a DBUtils.dll in my bin folder, is there a way to look inside a DLL to find out if there's a SQLEXpression method there?

Comment: Let X be the GUID from the default value of hkcr\DBUtils.SQLExpression\CLSID (in the registry), look in hkcr\clsid\X\inprocserver32 and you can see the dll its using - it needs to be registered and the whatever account the iis site is using need the appropriate permissions on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DBUtils.SQLExpression` is most probably an ActiveXDLL. Your best bet is to search for the DBUtils.dll or DBUtils.SQLExpression.dll file.

If it's available, you may need to register it to the COM server using `regsvr32` i.e. type `regsvr32 D:\MyPath\DBUtils.dll` in the run dialog and press enter.

You may also want to do a bit of error handling before setting an ActiveXObject in the session and see exactly what is the error. Something like this:

```
Dim sqlExpression
sqlExpression = Nothing

On Error Resume Next
Set sqlExpression = Server.CreateObject("DBUtils.SQLExpression")

If Err.Number <> 0 then
    Response.Write "#: " & Err.Number & ", Source: " & Err.Source & ", Description: " & Err.Description
Else
    'Rest of your code
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem that is a third party active-x plugin. Your posted code snippet creates an instanz of that and saves into a seesion with attribute 'SessionBoolian'.